# flash as2: how to create a popup alert while having a hidden stage?

Tags: flash, popup, actionscript-2, alert

I've created a main swf application that loads other swf files to use their classes (using getUrl()).
i would like that these swf files would output popup alert messages when errors occur without changing the main swf file. how can i do so ?

the external swf files that i load got a hidden stage which disallows me from viewing anything or seeing any message from them.

Using adobe flash, Action Script 2.

Answer (score 1):

If your swf is embedded in an HTML page, you could try:

```
message = "This is my error message text";
getURL("javascript:alert('"+message+"')", '');
```

Comment: thanks, but i would prefer something that's pure flash if it's possible.

Comment: You can't show a movieClip if your stage is hidden. You will need to put the contents of your stage in a movieClip so that you can hide the movieClip of main content and show the popup movieClip.

Otherwise this is one of the few solutions available to you.

Comment: i have a main swf with a stage, and it loads an swf that has a hidden stage. can i somehow from the 2nd swf, create an alert box and show it in the main stage of the main swf ?